# Android linking static library with Cmake

Tags: android, android-ndk, cmake

There is my CMake file:

```
add_library(lib_avcodec STATIC IMPORTED )
set_target_properties(lib_avcodec PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION
    ${distribution_DIR}/libsavcodec.a)
```

When I run project I receive next error

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
>   Expected output file at  path_to_library/libsavcodec.a for target lib_avcodec but there was none

Comment: Did you put prebuilt library at `path_to_library/libsavcodec.a` ?

Comment: Yes, I have prebuild library at path_to_library/libsavcodec.a